# How to ease and efficient store simulation data for numpy ufuncs in OO

Tags: python, numpy, oop, jupyter

In a jupyter notebook I OO-modeled a resource but in the control loop need to aggregate data over multiple objects being inefficient compared to ufuncs and similar operations. 
To package functionality i chose OO but for efficient and concise code i probably have to pull out the data into a storage class (maybe) and push all the ri[0] lines into a 2d array, in this case (2,K). 
The class does not need the log, only the last entries.

```
K = 100
class Resource:

    def __init__(self):
        self.log = np.random( (5,K) )
        # log gets filled during simulation

r0 = Resource()
r1 = Resource()

# while control loop:
    #aggregate control data
    for k in K:
        total_row_0 = r0.log[0][k] + r1.log[0][k]
    #do sth with the totals and loop again
```

This would greatly improves performance, but i have difficulty to link the data to the class if separately stored. How would you approach this? pandas DataFrames, np View or Shallow Copy?

```
[[...] #r0
 [...] ]#r1 same data into one array, efficient but map back to class difficult
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my take on it:

```
import numpy as np

K = 3
class Res:
    logs = 2
    def __init__(self):
        self.log = None

    def set_log(self, view):
        self.log = view

batteries = [Res(),  Res()]
d = {'Res': np.random.random( (Res.logs * len(batteries), K) )}        

for i in range(len(batteries)):
    view = d['Res'].view()[i::len(batteries)][:]
    batteries[i].set_log(view)

print(d)
batteries[1].log[1][2] = 1#test modifies view of last entry of second Res of second log
print(d)
```